# Why my label of Icon in antd is not displayed

Tags: javascript, icons, antd

This question confused me a long time,in my own project every time I want to use Icon of antd,it doesn't work.I don't know what's wrong,who knows please tell me,I am greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem,so foolish am I.I don't import the style,just add "import 'antd/dist/antd.css'; ".It's OK now,hoping this can help others new to antd like me.

Answer (score 0):

@Tian, I was stumped by that as well.  Your solution is exactly what worked for me.  Here's some code that worked for me:

```
import React from 'react';
import Icon from 'antd/lib/icon';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className='Header'>
          <span className='Header__title'>Happen</span>
          <a className='Icon' href='#' id='bangButton'>
            <Icon type='exclamation-circle-o'/>
          </a>
          <a className='Icon' href='#' id='plusButton'>
            <Icon type='plus-circle-o'/>
          </a>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises due to the missing css file that is required to antd component

Either add statement `import 'antd/dist/antd.css';` or create your own less file and import it.