# Ant Design Icon now showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, icons, antd

I've tried looking for solutions regarding this issue but nothing to have solve my problem with this. These are the posts I've looked up :

1. [Why my label of Icon in antd is not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838778/why-my-label-of-icon-in-antd-is-not-displayed)
2. [Why are the icons not showing up on my Ant Design sider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61788768/why-are-the-icons-not-showing-up-on-my-ant-design-sider)

I've not tried the second solution as this is a project in a company and I do not want to upgrade the version on my own without any permission.

Here's my code and imports:

```c
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import {Button} from 'antd';
import {TwitterOutlined} from '@ant-design/icons';    //import icons

//here is where i use the TwitterOutlined which is the icon
<Button type="link" href={links[3]} target="_blank" icon={<TwitterOutlined />}>Twitter</Button>
```

But the icon isn't showing up inside the button so I would appreciate if anyone knows what is exactly wrong with my imports or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code and it works with the latest antd, so almost definitely the same versioning situation as in that second question you linked. You can try getting around it [by using a custom icon](https://ant.design/components/icon/#components-icon-demo-custom).

```
import Icon from '@ant-design/icons';

const TwitterSVG = () => (
  <svg width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
    <path d="M24 4.557c-.883.392-1.832.656-2.828.775 1.017-.609 1.798-1.574 2.165-2.724-.951.564-2.005.974-3.127 1.195-.897-.957-2.178-1.555-3.594-1.555-3.179 0-5.515 2.966-4.797 6.045-4.091-.205-7.719-2.165-10.148-5.144-1.29 2.213-.669 5.108 1.523 6.574-.806-.026-1.566-.247-2.229-.616-.054 2.281 1.581 4.415 3.949 4.89-.693.188-1.452.232-2.224.084.626 1.956 2.444 3.379 4.6 3.419-2.07 1.623-4.678 2.348-7.29 2.04 2.179 1.397 4.768 2.212 7.548 2.212 9.142 0 14.307-7.721 13.995-14.646.962-.695 1.797-1.562 2.457-2.549" />
  </svg>
);

// ...
const TwitterIcon = props => <Icon component={TwitterSVG} {...props} />;

// ...
<TwitterIcon style={{ color: '#1DA1F2' }} /> // Twitter's blue
```

Comment: Thank you for youe help btw where did you get the path in the `svg` tag and also how do I include the `TwitterIcon` into my button

Comment: SVG from https://iconmonstr.com/twitter-1-svg. You just use that custom icon like any other component in React. Just set the button's icon property to {<TwitterIcon/>}

Comment: Just found out that I just have to use the icon name instead of importing icons from `@ant-design/icons` thank you for your help btw! Appreciate it!